# Ruby Base Class that Allows its Subclasses to Register for Callbacks

Tags: ruby, callback, metaprogramming

I want to write a base class in Ruby that allows classes that extend it to register for callbacks, much the way ApplicationController does with before_filter:

```
class AController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :foo

  def foo

  end
end
```

I want to write something like the other side of that before_filter myself.

```
class AClass < MyBase
  register_callback :callback1

  def callback1
    puts "called!"
  end

  def test
    call_me_maybe 5
  end
end
```

The `call_me_maybe` method is defined in the `MyBase` class and might call the callback that had previously been registered. What does the implementation of MyBase look like.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveSupport` provides a `Callbacks` module:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb

Your base class would look something like this example from `active_support/callbacks.rb`:

```
class Record
  include ActiveSupport::Callbacks
  define_callbacks :save

  def save
    run_callbacks :save do
      puts "- save"
    end
  end
end
```

See `callbacks.rb` for the full example.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it with `send`

```
class MyBase
  def self.register_callback name
    @@callback_name = name
  end

  def call_me_maybe num
    if num > 0
      self.send @@callback_name
    end
  end
end
```

Not sure if using send is bad for any reason... Seems like there ought to be another way...